# Python - registry.txt not found when librosa.load() used in pyinstaller exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, librosa

I have the following code

```py
file = "somefile.wav"
from librosa import load
data, samplerate = load(file, sr=None)
```

It works fine in a .py file but When I convert the .py file into .exe using `pyinstaller` it doesn't work anymore. It throws the following error.

```py
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "librosa\util\files.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "pooch\core.py", line 600, in load_registry
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\PCVISI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI208602\\librosa\\util\\example_data\\registry.txt'
[6848] Failed to execute script main
```

I tried re-installing librosa, and tried re-installing pooch as well.

Comment: Is the file missing from the PyInstaller bundle? Data files like this may not be automatically detected, and you may need to add them manually using a spec file, https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: can you please share an example.